# Prevent Microsoft OData Client from requesting Full Metadata

Tags: c#, json, odata, olingo

I am attempting to consume an Olingo OData Service with Microsoft.OData.Client.  For most requests, the client sends header `accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal`, but when I try to follow a navigation property (ie `GET http://localhost/odata.svc/Parent(key)/Children`), the client sends header `accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full`.  Olingo v4.2 does not support full metadata in JSON, and responds with HTTP 406 Not Acceptable.

Is there any way to force the Microsoft.OData.Client to use metadata=minimal, or is full metadata an intrinsic requirement of navigation properties?

Comment: And yes, I know that Olingo v4.3 supports full metadata, but I'd rather not upgrade if I can help it, and I'm not certain if that release is stable yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying to get this to work, I decided it was easier to edit the Olingo source code to generate full metadata than to try and get Microsoft.OData.Client to behave.  Open Source: 1, Microsoft: 0.